# Using Dependency Injection in .NET Core Service application

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, console

We have a service based application in .net core which would run as a daemon in Linux environment. Everything is working as expected but i am having problem in handling dependency injection.
Below is the code for reference

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting PreProcessor Application ");


        try
        {
            ConfigParameters.LoadSettings(args);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in setting config parameters {ex.Message}");
            return;
        }            

        IHost host = new HostBuilder()

            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddLogging();                    
                services.AddHostedService<MainService>();
                services.AddTransient<IMessageQueue, ActiveMQHandler>(x =>
                {
                    return new ActiveMQHandler(ConfigParameters.Settings.MessageQueueAddress);
                });
                services.AddTransient<IMessageQueue, ActiveMQHandler>(x =>
                {
                    return new ActiveMQHandler(ConfigParameters.Settings.MessageQueueAddress);
                });
                services.AddTransient<IMessageQueue, ActiveMQHandler>(x =>
                {
                    return new ActiveMQHandler(ConfigParameters.Settings.MessageQueueAddress);
                });
            })
            .Build();        

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Constructor for `MainService` looks like this

```
IApplicationLifetime appLifetime;
    IConfiguration configuration;
    PreProcessorQueueListener listener;
    private string reason = "SHUTDOWN SIGNAL";
    private IMessageQueue messageQueue;
    private IMessageQueue messageQueueSL;
    private IMessageQueue messageQueueSLProcess;
    public MainService(IConfiguration configuration, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IMessageQueue messageQueue, IMessageQueue messageQueueSL, IMessageQueue messageQueueSLProcess)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;            
        this.messageQueue = messageQueue;
        this.messageQueueSL = messageQueueSL;
        this.messageQueueSLProcess = messageQueueSLProcess;
        this.appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }
```

If you see in my `MainService` code i am passing three instances for `IMessageQueue` interface using constructor dependency injection. What i really want is based on a need in any part of the application i could grab a new instance of `ActiveMQHandler` class by passing `IMessageQueue` interface. Since i could not find a solution for this i am passing three instances (i am not happy with this solution) of `IMessageQueue`. If i need to use another instance of `ActiveMQHandler` class then i will have to pass fourth parameter as `IMessageQueue` interface in my `MainService` class.

What i am really looking for is use `ServiceProvider` (or something more elegant) and use that to get a new / singleton (based on how it is defined in `Program.cs`) instance of the class which implements the `IMessageQueue` interface.

An suggestions guys??

Answer (score 2):

If you change your MainService constructor signature to

```
public MainService(IConfiguration configuration, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IEnumerable<IMessageQueue> messageQueues)
```

you will be able to access all three interface implementations.

The problem might be if you need to identify them from the list, for example to perform different action on each implementation. If you need to perform the same action on each implementation than this will work.

Otherwise, you should consider using generic type to differentiate implementations injected.

Comment: Hi Dejan,How would I apply this method to all APIs? your email contact was not working https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/january/filtering-and-paging-in-aspnet-core-web-api/ I left a question here, asking to implement Pagination to all Apis. Trying to incorporate your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566698/generic-method-pagination-for-apis Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change the constructor to contain `IEnumerable<IMessageQueue>`.
It should give you a list of all registered IMessageQueue implementers.

Personally I do not like taking on dependencies on IApplicationLifetime or IServiceProvider in my classes. This is a bit like the ServiceLocator anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `IServiceProvider` into your class then use the `GetServices(typeof(IMessageQueue))` or the extension function `GetServices<IMessageQueue>()` that can be found within the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInejction` namespace. So something like this:

```
public MainService(IConfiguration configuration, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;            
    messageQueue = serviceProvider.GetServices<IMessageQueue>();
    messageQueueSL = serviceProvider.GetServices<IMessageQueue>();
    messageQueueSLProcess = serviceProvider.GetServices<IMessageQueue>();
    this.appLifetime = appLifetime;
}
```

There could be more elegant solutions based on what exactly you are using `IMessageQueue` for. It seems like `IMessageQueue` is for some kind of logging. For instance, let's say you needed a message queue for each class where `SLProcess` and `SL` were different classes. For such scenarios, you can inject a generic. So you can have something like this defined:

```
interface IMessageQueue<T> : IMessageQueue { }

class ActiveMQHandler<T> : ActiveMQHandler, IMessageQueue<T> {

    public string targetType => typeof(T).ToString();
}
```

With this you should be able to inject something like this: `AddTransient(typeof(IMessageQueue<>), typeof(ActiveMQHandler<>))`.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i have come with a solution which i think is elegant and is not dependent on constructor DI.
Idea is let the service (yes we have a microservice architecture) create the collection of dependencies in `IServiceCollection` and once the service is started any class whenever they want to resolve a Dependency they will just pass in the `Interface` and will get the instance of the concrete class.
My final code is like this. I have created a separate class in a common library

```
public class DependencyInjection
{
    private static ServiceProvider Provider;
    public static void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public static T GetService<T>()
    {
        var serviceScopeFactory = Provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my `Main` method in  `Program.cs` file looks like this

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting PreProcessor Application ");
        IServiceCollection servicesCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        try
        {
            ConfigParameters.LoadSettings(args);
            servicesCollection.AddScoped<IMessageQueue, ActiveMQHandler>(x =>
            {
                return new ActiveMQHandler("127.0.0.1");
            });
            DependencyInjection.AddServices(servicesCollection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine($"Error in setting config parameters {ex.Message}");
            return;
        }

        IHost host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
            {
                configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddLogging();
                services.AddHostedService<MainService>();                    
            })
            .Build();            

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

Now anywhere in the project when i need the instance of the ActiveMQHandler class i just write the below line of code

```
var messageQueue = DependencyInjection.GetService<IMessageQueue>();
```

Just for the information in my `Program.cs` i am using `AddScoped` but i have tested the code with `AddSingleton` also and everytime i requested for the concrete class instance it was the same.

The article at this link https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/ helped me

Comment: This is the ServiceLocator pattern. I strongly suggest you do not do this and reconsider using constructor injection to express your dependencies. This way, you are not letting the framework provide you with the dependency, what the inversion is all about, but you are requesting it from the DI container, which is almost the same as newing a dependency.